# What's the best way to manage multiple dependent projects in Git or Mercurial?

Tags: java, git, mercurial, project-management

I have a dozen Java projects that depend on each other, and I frequently make changes that cross-cut all of them. However, many of the projects are libraries that could be used independently of each other as well.

Right now I use mercurial subrepos, which works well except that very few third-party tools support it - it's hard to set up code review tools, continuous integration, etc.

What's the best way to address this situation? Split everything into separate projects and build separate JARs? Migrate to git and use git subrepositories? Check everything in to a single repo and accept that I have to check out everything to use anything? Something else?

Answer (score 4):

I would say the best way to do it would be to cut your dependencies so that they can reference as external jars. This way when you make potentially breaking changes you don't necessarily have to fix the affected areas straight away. Since they depend on a previously built jar it allows you to properly isolate your coding. If you use something like Maven to manage your dependencies you will also benefit from the ability to more easily keep track of the different versions of your jars.

Answer (score 4):

If the subprojects are sufficiently autonomous, I would advise setting them up as separate [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) projects with separate VCS repos.

This will give you the modularity you need paired with a working dependency management.